# Linked Inbox not opening

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, linked-accounts

i own a lumia 535. whenever i try to open it a "Resuming" window comes and the app closes down. Even I can't unstall it. What can I do now?

Comment: What app(s) does it do this for?